# Avoiding transients during filtering: Padding or Gustafsson's method?

Tags: filters, filter-design, filtering

I'm pretty uneducated when it comes to filtering, more of a stats guy, but I have to bandpass some signals and after a bunch of reading today I understand that the `scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt` function seems to be a gold standard. One thing I notice is that it doesn't provide the option to use the Gustafsson method for reducing transients as does regular ol' `scipy.signal.filtfilt` does. Which led me to wonder, is there much to argue for using the Gustafsson method over simple padding?

Comment: I would simply extrapolate the signal by $P$ samples in the front and back by fitting a polynomial function, and then remove the extrapolated part after filtering. Zero-padding should also work, but it also introduced abrupt shifts.